# How to modify an object depends on join condition in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects and alist of integers. Objects have property called exists.

```
public bool exists;
```

I need to join this two lists using left join and if ids exist in two lists, then set "exists" property to true;

I prepred dotnetfiddle example:

```
https://dotnetfiddle.net/sE1RIl
```

Expected result is (pseudocode):

```
Item1.exists = true;
Item2.exists = true;
Item3.exists = false;
```

Probably I will need to add more left joins later, so I am interested in the most flexible way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map your properties using `select` statement:

```
IEnumerable<Item> items = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item (){id =1, name = "Item1"},
    new Item (){id =2, name = "Item2"},
    new Item (){id =3, name = "Item3"}
};
List<int> ids = new List<int>() {1,2};

var param_1 = true;
var param_2 = false;
var param_3 = true;

var listOfItems = from item in items
    join id in ids on item.id equals id
    into result
    from r in result.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new Item
    {
        id = item.id,
        name = item.name,
        exists = (param_1 == true) ? true
            : (param_2 == false && param_3 == true) ? false 
                                                    : true
    };
```

Comment: Nice one. Thanks. Why I should use anonymous type? My Item class seems to be enough to return new instances of this class.

Comment: @justme Ooops, sorry, did not see your `Item` class in your fiddle. Please, see my updated answer. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Since your knowladge about c# seems to be large, I'd like to ask you how to assing function result to property in example like above. I am trying to do smth like this:
exists = () =>{
if(param1== true) return true; 
if (param2 == false && param3 == true) return false
}